# JXA – Throw Exceptions if Application Not Running (Race Condition Involved)

Tags: macos, applescript

Context: I've created a little status bar for [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) that displays some information from iTunes (song playing, artist, player position, etc). It does this by calling via the shell (in my case zsh) `$(osascript -l JavaScript script_file)`. The issue I've run into is to do with the default behaviour of method calls on application objects: If the application is closed, any calls open the application.

This is a problem for me because, since the tmux status bar is updated once a second, if the application closes after a check for it running is done but before a call is made, it reopens, which is a massive pain if I want to close the application.

Example code:

```
1  itunes = Application('iTunes')
2  
3  if (itunes.running()) {
4    return itunesStatusLine()
5  } else {
6    return '---'
7  }
```

You can see the race condition between the if and return.

What I've considered:

1. Detaching all tmux sessions before closing. This is annoying to do manually, but scriptable, and it avoids the problem altogether. However it's a workaround, not a solution.
2. Getting all necessary data from iTunes up-front, wrapping every call in its own if-else block, passing the data to the status line function, and throwing an exception when one fails. This doesn't solve the problem, but it might mitigate it by failing earlier and (hopefully) faster. (While maintaining my sanity. I want to extend this thing further, and putting the same try-catch blocks around every call just sounds messy.)
3. Slow-down the tmux status bar update. Again, workaround, not solution, and it would kinda shoot the sharability of the code in the foot. It's not uncommon to have 1 second updates on the status line (clocks using seconds come to mind).

I think the ideal solution would be using a method call that raises an exception if the application is closed instead of opening the application. If there is any way to do such a thing with JXA, I'm at a loss. I've sifted through the docs (what's in the Script Editor library and the scraps I could find online) and come-up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying, but I have:

```
/**
 * Checks to see if an app is running.
 *
 * @param appName   -   Text containing the Application ID, Application Name or Process Name of the application.
 * @return          -   True if the app is running, false if the app is not running.
 */
function isAppRunning(appName) {
    try {
        return Application(appName).running();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works for me and does not cause an app to start. If no such app exists, it simply returns false (not running).